# Why am I getting a NoneType error in the second repetition of a loop?

Tags: python, loops, sensors

I am coding a loop that continuously reads out the readings from two sensors. However, I am getting this error every time on the second repetition. I am using the DHT22 sensor, and using the pigpio library.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1426, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 490, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/pigpio_dht22/TempHumSensorDisplayWindow3.py", line 42, in loop
    humidity, tempb = readDHT22()
  File "/home/pi/pigpio_dht22/TempHumSensorDisplayWindow3.py", line 34, in readDHT22
    s.trigger()
  File "/home/pi/pigpio_dht22/DHT22.py", line 230, in trigger
    self.pi.write(self.gpio, pigpio.LOW)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 1381, in write
    return _u2i(_pigpio_command(self.sl, _PI_CMD_WRITE, gpio, level))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 983, in _pigpio_command
    sl.s.send(struct.pack('IIII', cmd, p1, p2, 0))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
import Adafruit_MAX31855.MAX31855 as MAX31855
import datetime
import pigpio
from time import sleep
pi = pigpio.pi()
import DHT22

CLK = 25
CS  = 24
DO  = 18
sensor = MAX31855.MAX31855(CLK, CS, DO)
s = DHT22.sensor(pi, 4)



master = Tk()
master.wm_title('Ethane Pot Temp')
lab = Label(master, width=25)
labb = Label(master, width=25)
Label(master, width=25, text='Ethane Pot Temperature').grid(row=1, column=1)
Label(master, width=25, text='Chamber Humidity').grid(row=2, column=1)
lab.grid(row=1, column=2)
labb.grid(row=2, column=2)
temp = sensor.readTempC()
tempa = StringVar()
s.trigger()


def readDHT22():
    #Get a new reading
    s.trigger()
    #Save our value
    humidity = '%.2f' % (s.humidity())
    tempb = '%.2f' % (s.temperature())
    return (humidity, tempb)

def loop():
    sleep(.03)
    humidity, tempb = readDHT22()
    print(tempb)
    print(humidity)
    temp = sensor.readTempC()
    tempa.set(str(temp))
    lab.config(text=tempa.get())
    master.after(2000, loop)

loop()
s.cancel()
pi.stop()
master.mainloop()
```

I am using a tkinter window, and therefore cannot use while True as the loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have **no idea** of anything, but is it possible that after the first read something closes? The fact that you're only calling this `temp = sensor.readTempC()` once looks *suspicious*... As if you had to do that on every iteration of the loop? Again: I have no idea about TkInter or your sensor or... nothing, but it's a behavior I've seen before, with things likes sockets and such.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried adding it to the loop, but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have documentation for the sensor objects you're using?  Is a sensor capable of making two consecutive readings, or do you have to do something special in between?

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm using the DHT22 and the MAX31855. The MAX31855 works well, but the DHT22 isn't working. There must be a two second delay between each reading for the DHT22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are prematurely disposing of the DHT22 sensor variable and the PiGPIO daemon.
You should not clean up the resources until the program is exiting.  Change the end of your program as follows:

```
def on_closing():
    print('Cleaning up resources.')
    s.cancel()
    pi.stop()
    master.destroy()

master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
loop()
master.mainloop()
```

Additionally the *sleep(.03)* method should be moved to the line directly after the *s.trigger()* method.  I'm referring to the trigger in the *readDHT22()* function.  The trigger at the top of your code is superfluous and should be removed.  The delay after the trigger is only necessary on faster Pi's to ensure the trigger completes prior to reading the temperature and humidity.